# Required changes to be made to the config.rb file paths for a custom theme

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, sass

This is my first experience with sass and my novice steps into learning magento 1.9 theme development.

I have followed the following guide to create the base for my custom theme-
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide

After creating the config.rb file inside the following folder: `xampp\htdocs\magento\skin\frontend\custom_package\custom_theme\scss\`

What paths do I need to change to the following sample snippet for my new sass compilation to work-

```
http_path = "/skin/frontend/rwd/default/"
css_dir = "../css"
sass_dir = "../scss"
images_dir = "../images"
javascripts_dir = "../js"
relative_assets = true
```

Also where do I need to tinker the sass codes for the proper css code to be generated for my theme.

-Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command xampp\htdocs\magento\skin\frontend\custom_package\custom_theme\scss\compass watch . works, you don't have to change anything.